# Flake8 check ok

Tags: python, flake8

I recently got a problem: I did a fresh ubuntu 22.04 setup, installed vim and flake8. After opening my .py file, flake8 doesn't show any errors (even of there are some, I did them on purpose). Is there anything I could do?
Other plugins work, there is no problem with them, it's just flake8.
When I run `flake8 xyz.py` in my terminal it works and also shows the errors.
I am using vim 8.2 on ubuntu 22.04
I also installed the vim-flake8 plugin from github

Comment: Presumably there's some plugin that vim uses to enable flake8 warnings, and you don't have it on your fresh install?

Comment: Do you know what plugin this is? The other problem is that even after running the flake8 check in vim (with F7) it always shows ```flake8 check ok```

Comment: I'd _guess_ https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8 (since it contains `Flake8 check OK`, different casing though), but no real idea.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't mention it, I have already installed it in vim, that's the plugin I have the problem with

Comment: Well, this seems relevant: https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8/issues/29

Answer (score -1):

Ok I got it fixed, I did a mistake because my $PATH in vim was set to zsh which is not installed anymore. After changing the shell to /bin/sh it's working again.
If anybody needs help:
`set shell=/bin/sh`